# Не работает HTTP2 в nginx

Tags: nginx, http2

Решил наконец перейти на http/2. У меня на компьютере и android-смартфоне всё в полном порядке. Но заметил, что на iPhone в Safari и через прокси сайт просто не открывается. Белый экран. Почему это происходит? И можно ли по возможности сделать не принудительный http2?

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        limit_conn addr 10;
        if ($http_host ~ "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}") {
            return 444;
        }
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://jamesjgoodwin.ru$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;

    root /var/www/;
    index index.php index.html;

    client_body_timeout 5s;
    client_header_timeout 5s;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        access_log        off;
        expires           max;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.key;
}
```

Comment: HTTPS настроен? Покажи конфиг nginx.

Comment: @MrClon добавил конфиг

Comment: я на своем одном проекте также использовал http2, пока не зашел туда фаерфоксом. Он просто сказал "у вас ненормально настроена секюрити" и отказался открывать сайт. Пришлось откатиться к старому доброму http/1.1. Похоже, в http2 нашли багу и фаерфокс воспринял все буквально. С сафари видимо тоже самое

Comment: @KoVadim а может просто проблемы с сертификатом?

Comment: на обычном то https работает. Сертификат от let's encrypt

Comment: какая версия ios стоит?

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы с настройками ssl. Воспользуйтесь [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). В разделе "Handshake Simulation" теста Вашего домена Вы сможете найти поведение для различных браузеров и ОС. На этом же сайте можно найти рекомендуемые настройки для ssl.